# Plot line between all the scattered points and adjust the thickness of line according to the distance between points

Tags: matlab, format, matlab-figure, scatter-plot

Here are the coordinates that I am planning to plot, filename is Coords:

```
x       y
0.0110  0.1105
-0.2730 0.2559
0.3610  0.1528
-0.0077 -0.2520
-0.2412 -0.1979
0.0444  -0.0526
0.0543  -0.0076
-0.1710 0.1170
0.12741 -0.0448
0.0949  -0.0811
```

Here is my code that plots the scatter graph first:

```
Hold on
%Plot Coordinate
For i=1:10
    dot_size = 100;
    scatter ( Coords(i,1) ,Coords(i,2), dot_size, 'filled', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k' );
end

%Draw line distance between each points
for i=1:10
     for j=1:10
          plot( [Coords(i,1) Coords(i,2)], [Coords(j,1) Coords(j,2)] );
     end
end
Hold off

%Sets the size of the y and x axis
xlim( [ min( Coords(:,1)) max( Coords(:,1)) ] );
ylim( [ min( Coords(:,2)) max( Coords(:,2)) ] );
axis off;
```

Here is the result I get:

[image: scatter figure]

I don't know why the lines are being drawn everywhere. I also notice that even when `plot(x,y) = 0`, the line is still being drawn.

I also would like to change the thickness and opacity of the line depending on the distance between the two points: E.g. thicker and darker line for short distance between points. And thinner /lighter line if the distance between two points are long.

I want my plot to look something like this:

[image: Ideal result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your lines do not match the scattered points is the coordinates you give to `plot`; The coordinates are in wrong order and therefore they do not define the lines correctly.

I modified your code to correct this issue. I replaced `plot` with `line`, but you can also do the same with `plot`. In addition, I defined the [anonymous functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) `f` and `g` to define the color and thickness of each line based on distance of the two ends, `d`. You can modify these functionalities to get different graphical behaviors.

```
n = 10; % number of points
dot_size = 100;
Coords = rand(n, 2);
% maximum possible length in your coordination plane:
L = norm([max(Coords(:,1))-min(Coords(:,1)),max(Coords(:,2))-min(Coords(:,2))]);
% this function defines the line width:
f = @(x) L / (x + 0.1); % 0.1 avoids huge line widths in very small distances
% this function defines the color:
g = @(x) x * [1 1 1] / L;
figure
hold on
for ii = 1:n-1
     for jj = ii+1:n
         d = norm([Coords(ii,1)-Coords(jj,1), Coords(ii,2)-Coords(jj,2)]);
         line([Coords(ii,1) Coords(jj,1)], [Coords(ii,2) Coords(jj,2)], ...
             'LineWidth', f(d), 'Color', g(d));
     end
end
scatter (Coords(:,1), Coords(:,2), dot_size, 'filled', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k');
axis tight
axis off
```

With this output:

[image]

**Notes:**

1. `axis tight` is a command that sets the limits to the tightest possible. It is equivalent to your `xlim( [ min( Coords(:,1)) max( Coords(:,1)) ] );` and the next line.
2. In the `for`-loops you should try to avoid choosing one pair of points twice or same point as both sides of a line.
3. For scattering you do not need a loop. It could all be done at once.
4. I brought `scatter` after plotting the lines, so the circles are drawn on top.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a specialized MATLAB function for generating plots like this: `gplot`.

```
  data = [
    0.0110  0.1105
    -0.2730 0.2559
    0.3610  0.1528
    -0.0077 -0.2520
    -0.2412 -0.1979
    0.0444  -0.0526
    0.0543  -0.0076
    -0.1710 0.1170
    0.12741 -0.0448
    0.0949  -0.0811]; % Coordinates

    adjM = squareform(pdist(data)); % 
    adjM (adjM > 0) = 1; % Form adjacency matrix based on Euclidean distances


figure; gplot(adjM, data, '-o') % Plot figure based on coordinates and adjacency matrix
```

[image]

Then, customize to your liking, e.g. if you want to change marker type, remove the axis, add labels etc.

Comment: This is really helpful as well! Thank you very much!